# Rails Live Streaming doesn't stream live

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, streaming, live

I'ld like to use live streaming feature introduced with rails 4. In my application it didn't work so I just created a extremely simple example. But this also doesn't stream the content. It opens the connection, waits until all 10 runs have passed and then streams the contend.

Here is the example code.

- First, I created a new rails application with rails 4.0.2
- Second I add gem 'puma' so that live streaming is supported

The controller is looking like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
include ActionController::Live

def index
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
        10.times {
          response.stream.write "This is a test Messagen"
          sleep 1
        }
        response.stream.close
    end
end
```

I used curl for testing:

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/my
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-UA-Compatible: chrome=1
Content-Type: text/event-stream
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: request_method=GET; path=/
X-Request-Id: 7bdf30a2-158b-40ce-81c8-651914c7b5df
X-Runtime: 0.048783
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

This is a test MessagenThis is a test MessagenThis is a test MessagenThis is a test 
MessagenThis is a test MessagenThis is a test MessagenThis is a test MessagenThis is a test 
MessagenThis is a test MessagenThis is a test Messagen
```

But it lasts 10 seconds until the Messages are written all together (not one every second).

I found this code example on a lot of pages on the internet - but didn't know what went wrong.

Any Idea?

Comment: I found out, that this was a third party issue. Using influxdb-rails "destroys" the live streaming ability. They fixed this in there development version for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe you need a newline in order to get it to stream with curl.

```
response.stream.write "This is a test Messagen\n"

curl localhost:3000

This is a test Messagen
This is a test Messagen
This is a test Messagen
This is a test Messagen
This is a test Messagen
```

The newline (\n) seems to allow the streaming to happen incrementally with the sleep instead of waiting the entire block of time and then spitting out the results at once.

For actually rendering to a view (with EventSource) you will need to set

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
```

This will work "ok" for a hello world, but for something that is solid and scalable I would go with Redis instead of looping when you finally get to pulling from the database.